# Передача с помощью jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

У меня есть 2 php файла. В одном выводятся тесты состоящие из заголовка, описания и кнопки. при нажатии кнопки должен открываться определенный тест. Данные берутся из базы данных. Выводятся они данным образом:

```
<?php
    while ($test = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?> <h2><?=$test['name_test']?></h2>
        <p><?=$test['description']?></p>
        <button  onClick="reply_click(this)" id="<?=$test['id_test']; ?>" >Открыть тест</button>
       <?php print_r($id);
       }
    ?>
```

Необходимо брать id нажатой кнопки для этого выполнила

```
<script>
function reply_click(obj)
    {
        let id = obj.id;
        alert(id);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            method: 'post',
            data: {text: 'id'},
            });
        location.href="test.php";
    }
</script>
```

В файле в который отправляю выглядит так прописала

```
echo 'Данные приняты - '.$_POST['text'];
```

Данные из БД выводятся, id получается, но данные не передаются в файл test.php.
Испробовала разные варианты, но так и не смогла решить проблему. Можно ли выполнить данную операцию другим способом?

Comment: Ты неправильно понимаешь (точнее не понимаешь) принцип работы серверной части и взаимодействия клиента и сервера....Если ты в аяксе пропишешь получение данных от скприта `success: function(data) {
  console.log(data)
      }`  то вполне в консоли браузера сможешь увидеть ответ

Comment: Только предварительно надо удалить бестолковый вызов `location.href="test.php";`